# Wordpress wp_list_pages to show "current_page_item" as first element

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, navigation

i want the element containing class  "current_page_item" to be in the top when rendering the navigation, is it possible to do so in wordpress? If yes, maybe you can help me out with a solution..

```
       <div class="sidebar">
            <?php
            if ( is_page() && $post->post_parent ) {

                $args = array(
                    'order' => 'ASC',
                    'post_parent' => $post->parent,
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'post_type' => 'page'
                );

                $children = wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=' . $post->post_parent . '&echo=0' );
            }
            else {
                $children = wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=' . $post->ID . '&echo=0' );

                $args = array(
                    'order' => 'ASC',
                    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'post_type' => 'page'
                );
            }

            if ( $children) : ?>
                <ul class="sidebar-list">
                    <?php echo $children; ?>
                </ul>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are trying to achieve here, could you please elaborate?

Comment: Hello Tee, when rendering the sidebar navigation, I want that the LI with class current_page_item would be number one in the navigation ( on top off all other navigation list items)

Comment: Hey, i'm going to propose a alternative solution (which is a bit weird but hey better then nothing). You can style the current_page_item class with CSS so that one is always in front. By 'prepending' it just before the navigation.

Comment: well thats better then nothing. can you post a code snippet ?

Comment: What you want to do is to use the wp_list_pages filter found at https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_list_pages/

This will run whenever you call wp_list_pages() and inside the filter function you can make changes you require.

Many solutions suggest you could also use a custom walker so this might also be worth a look at the items below

http://hookr.io/filters/wp_list_pages/

https://snipplr.com/view/54404/wordpress-custom-sitemap-shortcode-following-custom-menu-order/